# Web Service return XML in swift

Tags: swift

How can i connect to a web service and get the result as an `XML` format in `SWIFT`

**Note:** The web service return `XML` Format

I tried this code below but it's not work

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    (data, response, error) in

    if data == nil {
        println("dataTaskWithRequest error: \(error)")
        return
    }

    let parser = NSXMLParser(data: data)
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse()

    // you can now check the value of the `success` variable here
}
task.resume()
```

// but obviously don't try to use it here here

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Is data nil? Is the error parameter not nit? Did you set all the NSXMLParserDelegates? Are they called?

Comment: What do you mean saying it doesn't work? Parse error, request error, trash data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSURLConnection` and its delegete method to get the XML data and `NSXMLParser` and its delegate methods to parse it and save it to your models.

[XMLParser Tutorial](http://iosbala.blogspot.in/2013/04/how-to-using-nsxmlparser-in-iphone-sdk.html)

[NSURLConnection Tutorial](http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/)

Comment: Thanks toofani, i will try the tutorial and get back to you.